# Maximize throughput sending emails concurrently

Tags: .net, async-await

I'm working on a Windows Service that picks up a batch of items (e-mails) from a queue (SQL Server table) and sends the items concurrently.

Since I'm using .NET 4.5 I implemented all the methods with `async/await`. I started with a batch size of 10. The logic pulls the records from the db, creates 10 `Task` followed by `Task.WhenAll()` before hitting the db again. It took about 89 seconds to send 100 emails.

Then I tried a batch size of 100/100 Tasks.

I was expecting a huge increase in throughput since sending emails is an async operarion but it took about 79 seconds for the same 100 emails. Not a big improvement.

Where is the bottleneck? Maybe not enough threads on the `ThreadPool`? Maybe the SMTP server (Amazon SES) is throttling concurrent connections?

Comment: i think Amazon should support bulk message sending, anyway you try to use amazon queue service(http://aws.amazon.com/en/sqs/)

Comment: Actually the problem is not the queue implementation but sending the emails as fast as possible

Comment: I'd try some simple logging to the console or something to time and count your tasks.

Comment: “Where is the bottleneck?” How are we supposed to figure that out? You need to measure that by yourself, we can only guess.

Comment: Aren't you trying to reimplement `Parallel.ForEach`? Have you looked at [DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh228603.aspx)? Aren't you reaching the limit of connections to the same host?

Comment: @Paulo, you were right, I was reaching the max number of connections, which is 2 by default. Parallel.ForEach makes sense for CPU-bound Tasks, where the number of concurrent tasks is directly related to the number of cores. In my case the Tasks are I/O bound, which means most of the times they idle waiting for the SMTP client to send the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://michaeldimoudis.com/blog/2013/5/25/reliably-and-speedily-send-mass-emails-via-amazon-ses-in-c).

It's a matter of increasing the max number of concurrent connections. I added this to the App.config and all 10 connections take place concurrently:

```
<system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
        <add address="*" maxconnection="10" />
    </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```